# Form submit inside div loaded through ajax not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The following is my showproduct.jsp file... So when i search for a product the div with `id`, `ajax` section loads the content from searchproduct.jsp. But when try performing submit in the forms created in the ajaxsection div it is not working.

This is my SHOWPRODUCT.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
  System.out.println(username);
  %>
  <center>
  <h2 style="color:red;"><% if(request.getParameter("msg")!=null) {
    out.println(request.getParameter("msg"));
}%></h2>
<form action=""> 
Product Search: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value)">
</form>


  <h2>Product List </h2>

  <div id="ajaxsection"></div>
  <table id="productlist" border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
  <th>ProductID</th>
  <th>ProductName</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Available</th>
  </tr>
   <%   PreparedStatement pst = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        String sql = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/shop", "root", "");
            sql = "select * from product";
            System.out.println("Product List");
            pst = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) { %>

            <% if(rs.getInt("quantity") > 0 ) { %>

            <tr>
            <form id="forms1"  action="AddCart1" method="POST">
            <td><%=rs.getString("productid")%></td>

            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<%=rs.getString("productid")%>">
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%=username%>">
            <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="<%= request.getParameter("uri") %>">
            <td><%=rs.getString("productname")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getInt("price")%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getInt("quantity")%></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"></td>
            </form>
            </tr>

           <% }
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }%>
</table>
<br><br>
</center>
<script>
function showproduct(str) {

  var xhttp;    
  if (str == "") { 
    var x = document.getElementById('productlist');
    x.style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.getElementById("ajaxsection").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      var x = document.getElementById('productlist');
      x.style.display = 'none';
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("ajaxsection").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      eval(document.getElementById("runscript").innerHTML);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "searchproduct.jsp?name="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my SEARCHPRODUCT.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>

<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<% String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
  System.out.println(username);
  String s=request.getParameter("name"); 
  %>
    <body>
    <center>
  <h2 style="color:red;"><% if(request.getParameter("msg")!=null) {
    out.println(request.getParameter("msg"));
}%></h2>
  <table  border="1" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
  <th>ProductID</th>
  <th>ProductName</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Available</th>
  </tr>
   <%   PreparedStatement pst1 = null;
        Connection conn1 = null;
        String sql1 = "";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/shop", "root", "");
            sql1 = "select * from product";
            System.out.println("Product List");

             pst1=conn1.prepareStatement("select * from product where productname LIKE ?");  
            s+="%";
            pst1.setString(1,s);  
            ResultSet rs1 = pst1.executeQuery();
            while (rs1.next()) { %>

            <% if(rs1.getInt("quantity") > 0 ) { %>

            <tr>
            <form id="forms" action="AddCart1" method="POST">
            <td><%=rs1.getString("productid")%></td>

            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<%=rs1.getString("productid")%>">
            <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<%=username%>">
            <input type="hidden" name="uri" value="<%= request.getParameter("uri") %>">
            <td><%=rs1.getString("productname")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getInt("price")%></td>
            <td><%=rs1.getInt("quantity")%></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart"></td>
            </form>
            </tr>

           <% }
           }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (conn1 != null) {
                try {
                    conn1.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }%>
</table>
<br><br>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript" id="runscript">
alert("running from mainssss");
//document.getElementById("forms").submit();
var f = document.getElementById("forms");
f.onsubmit = function (e){
    alert("running from mainssss111");
    if(document.getElementById("forms")!=null)
    document.getElementById("forms").submit();
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(f.name.value); 
    }



</script>
    </body>
```

Comment: please define "not working." This is not an error message or problem statement. Please explain what debugging steps you have taken and what you have discovered. Where does it stop working? Do you get any errors (in the browser console, and/or on the server? Do you get some other unexpected behaviour instead? It should be possible to narrow down the problem to one area of this code; as it stands the problem could be anywhere.

Comment: I figured out the issue... Each row of the table cant be a form... Instead have each row as a seperate table then we can have it as a form. And the submit works as expected.

Comment: well, you could have each row as a form if that would be the most useful thing. Your problem was that all your forms had the same ID, which is invalid HTML. So your getElementById function would only ever find the first form with that ID and ignore all the others. But if one form works for what you need to do, then that's a good solution too.